Third Person Character Controller Scales Vertical Terrain in Unity Game Engine
I am working on a game using Unity with the StarterAssets Third Person Character Controller, but I'm encountering an issue where my character is able to walk, stand, and even jump on vertical walls. This behavior is unintended as players should not be able to move up vertical surfaces unless they are climbing a ladder.
I want to prevent the character from scaling vertical surfaces but still allow them to move on slopes that are walkable. The only exception for vertical movement should be when they are climbing a ladder.
Code from: https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/essentials/starter-assets-thirdperson-updates-in-new-charactercontroller-pa-196526
using UnityEngine;
#if ENABLE_INPUT_SYSTEM 
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;
#endif

/* Note: animations are called via the controller for both the character and capsule using animator null checks*/

namespace StarterAssets
{

    [RequireComponent(typeof(CharacterController))]

#if ENABLE_INPUT_SYSTEM
    [RequireComponent(typeof(PlayerInput))]
#endif

    public class ThirdPersonController : MonoBehaviour
    {

        [Header("Player")]
        [Tooltip("Move speed of the character in m/s")]
        public float MoveSpeed = 2.0f;

        [Tooltip("Sprint speed of the character in m/s")]
        public float SprintSpeed = 5.335f;

        [Tooltip("How fast the character turns to face movement direction")]
        [Range(0.0f, 0.3f)]
        public float RotationSmoothTime = 0.12f;

        [Tooltip("Acceleration and deceleration")]
        public float SpeedChangeRate = 10.0f;

        public AudioClip LandingAudioClip;
        public AudioClip[] FootstepAudioClips;
        [Range(0, 1)] public float FootstepAudioVolume = 0.5f;

        [Space(10)]
        [Tooltip("The height the player can jump")]
        public float JumpHeight = 1.2f;

        [Tooltip("The character uses its own gravity value. The engine default is -9.81f")]
        public float Gravity = -15.0f;

        [Space(10)]
        [Tooltip("Time required to pass before being able to jump again. Set to 0f to instantly jump again")]
        public float JumpTimeout = 0.50f;

        [Tooltip("Time required to pass before entering the fall state. Useful for walking down stairs")]
        public float FallTimeout = 0.15f;

        [Header("Player Grounded")]
        [Tooltip("If the character is grounded or not. Not part of the CharacterController built in grounded check")]
        public bool Grounded = true;

        [Tooltip("Useful for rough ground")]
        public float GroundedOffset = -0.14f;

        [Tooltip("The radius of the grounded check. Should match the radius of the CharacterController")]
        public float GroundedRadius = 0.28f;

        [Tooltip("What layers the character uses as ground")]
        public LayerMask GroundLayers;

        [Header("Cinemachine")]
        [Tooltip("The follow target set in the Cinemachine Virtual Camera that the camera will follow")]
        public GameObject CinemachineCameraTarget;

        [Tooltip("How far in degrees can you move the camera up")]
        public float TopClamp = 70.0f;

        [Tooltip("How far in degrees can you move the camera down")]
        public float BottomClamp = -30.0f;

        [Tooltip("Additional degress to override the camera. Useful for fine tuning camera position when locked")]
        public float CameraAngleOverride = 0.0f;

        [Tooltip("For locking the camera position on all axis")]
        public bool LockCameraPosition = false;

        // cinemachine
        private float _cinemachineTargetYaw;
        private float _cinemachineTargetPitch;

        // player
        private float _speed;
        private float _animationBlend;
        private float _targetRotation = 0.0f;
        private float _rotationVelocity;
        private float _verticalVelocity;
        private float _terminalVelocity = 53.0f;

        // timeout deltatime
        private float _jumpTimeoutDelta;
        private float _fallTimeoutDelta;

        // animation IDs
        private int _animIDSpeed;
        private int _animIDGrounded;
        private int _animIDJump;
        private int _animIDFreeFall;
        private int _animIDMotionSpeed;

#if ENABLE_INPUT_SYSTEM
        private PlayerInput _playerInput;
#endif

        private Animator _animator;
        private CharacterController _controller;
        private StarterAssetsInputs _input;
        private GameObject _mainCamera;

        private const float _threshold = 0.01f;

        private bool _hasAnimator;

        private bool IsCurrentDeviceMouse
        {
            get
            {

#if ENABLE_INPUT_SYSTEM
                return _playerInput.currentControlScheme == "KeyboardMouse";
#else
                    return false;
#endif

            }
        }


        private void Awake()
        {

            // get a reference to our main camera
            if (_mainCamera == null)
            {

                _mainCamera = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MainCamera");

            }
        }

        private void Start()
        {

            _cinemachineTargetYaw = CinemachineCameraTarget.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y;

            _hasAnimator = TryGetComponent(out _animator);
            _controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
            _input = GetComponent<StarterAssetsInputs>();
#if ENABLE_INPUT_SYSTEM
            _playerInput = GetComponent<PlayerInput>();
#else
                Debug.LogError( "Starter Assets package is missing dependencies. Please use Tools/Starter Assets/Reinstall Dependencies to fix it");
#endif

            AssignAnimationIDs();

            // reset our timeouts on start
            _jumpTimeoutDelta = JumpTimeout;
            _fallTimeoutDelta = FallTimeout;
        }

        private void Update()
        {

            _hasAnimator = TryGetComponent(out _animator);

            JumpAndGravity();
            GroundedCheck();
            Move();

        }

        private void LateUpdate()
        {

            CameraRotation();

        }

        private void AssignAnimationIDs()
        {

            _animIDSpeed = Animator.StringToHash("Speed");
            _animIDGrounded = Animator.StringToHash("Grounded");
            _animIDJump = Animator.StringToHash("Jump");
            _animIDFreeFall = Animator.StringToHash("FreeFall");
            _animIDMotionSpeed = Animator.StringToHash("MotionSpeed");

        }

        private void GroundedCheck()
        {

            // set sphere position, with offset
            Vector3 spherePosition = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y - GroundedOffset, transform.position.z);
            Grounded = Physics.CheckSphere(spherePosition, GroundedRadius, GroundLayers, QueryTriggerInteraction.Ignore);

            // update animator if using character
            if (_hasAnimator)
            {

                _animator.SetBool(_animIDGrounded, Grounded);

            }

        }

        private void CameraRotation()
        {

            // if there is an input and camera position is not fixed
            if (_input.look.sqrMagnitude >= _threshold && !LockCameraPosition)
            {

                //Don't multiply mouse input by Time.deltaTime;
                float deltaTimeMultiplier = IsCurrentDeviceMouse ? 1.0f : Time.deltaTime;

                _cinemachineTargetYaw += _input.look.x * deltaTimeMultiplier;
                _cinemachineTargetPitch += _input.look.y * deltaTimeMultiplier;

            }

            // clamp our rotations so our values are limited 360 degrees
            _cinemachineTargetYaw = ClampAngle(_cinemachineTargetYaw, float.MinValue, float.MaxValue);
            _cinemachineTargetPitch = ClampAngle(_cinemachineTargetPitch, BottomClamp, TopClamp);

            // Cinemachine will follow this target
            CinemachineCameraTarget.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(_cinemachineTargetPitch + CameraAngleOverride, _cinemachineTargetYaw, 0.0f);

        }

        private void Move()
        {

            // set target speed based on move speed, sprint speed and if sprint is pressed
            float targetSpeed = _input.sprint ? SprintSpeed : MoveSpeed;

            // a simplistic acceleration and deceleration designed to be easy to remove, replace, or iterate upon

            // note: Vector2's == operator uses approximation so is not floating point error prone, and is cheaper than magnitude
            // if there is no input, set the target speed to 0
            if (_input.move == Vector2.zero) targetSpeed = 0.0f;

            // a reference to the players current horizontal velocity
            float currentHorizontalSpeed = new Vector3(_controller.velocity.x, 0.0f, _controller.velocity.z).magnitude;

            float speedOffset = 0.1f;
            float inputMagnitude = _input.analogMovement ? _input.move.magnitude : 1f;

            // accelerate or decelerate to target speed
            if (currentHorizontalSpeed < targetSpeed - speedOffset || currentHorizontalSpeed > targetSpeed + speedOffset)
            {

                // creates curved result rather than a linear one giving a more organic speed change
                // note T in Lerp is clamped, so we don't need to clamp our speed
                _speed = Mathf.Lerp(currentHorizontalSpeed, targetSpeed * inputMagnitude, Time.deltaTime * SpeedChangeRate);

                // round speed to 3 decimal places
                _speed = Mathf.Round(_speed * 1000f) / 1000f;

            }

            else
            {

                _speed = targetSpeed;

            }

            _animationBlend = Mathf.Lerp(_animationBlend, targetSpeed, Time.deltaTime * SpeedChangeRate);
            if (_animationBlend < 0.01f) _animationBlend = 0f;

            // normalise input direction
            Vector3 inputDirection = new Vector3(_input.move.x, 0.0f, _input.move.y).normalized;

            // note: Vector2's != operator uses approximation so is not floating point error prone, and is cheaper than magnitude
            // if there is a move input rotate player when the player is moving
            if (_input.move != Vector2.zero)
            {

                _targetRotation = Mathf.Atan2(inputDirection.x, inputDirection.z) * Mathf.Rad2Deg + _mainCamera.transform.eulerAngles.y;
                float rotation = Mathf.SmoothDampAngle(transform.eulerAngles.y, _targetRotation, ref _rotationVelocity, RotationSmoothTime);

                // rotate to face input direction relative to camera position
                transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0.0f, rotation, 0.0f);

            }


            Vector3 targetDirection = Quaternion.Euler(0.0f, _targetRotation, 0.0f) * Vector3.forward;

            // move the player
            _controller.Move(targetDirection.normalized * (_speed * Time.deltaTime) + new Vector3(0.0f, _verticalVelocity, 0.0f) * Time.deltaTime);

            // update animator if using character
            if (_hasAnimator)
            {

                _animator.SetFloat(_animIDSpeed, _animationBlend);
                _animator.SetFloat(_animIDMotionSpeed, inputMagnitude);

            }

        }

        private void JumpAndGravity()
        {

            if (Grounded)
            {

                // reset the fall timeout timer
                _fallTimeoutDelta = FallTimeout;

                // update animator if using character
                if (_hasAnimator)
                {

                    _animator.SetBool(_animIDJump, false);
                    _animator.SetBool(_animIDFreeFall, false);

                }

                // stop our velocity dropping infinitely when grounded
                if (_verticalVelocity < 0.0f)
                {

                    _verticalVelocity = -2f;

                }

                // Jump
                if (_input.jump && _jumpTimeoutDelta <= 0.0f)
                {

                    // the square root of H * -2 * G = how much velocity needed to reach desired height
                    _verticalVelocity = Mathf.Sqrt(JumpHeight * -2f * Gravity);

                    // update animator if using character
                    if (_hasAnimator)
                    {

                        _animator.SetBool(_animIDJump, true);

                    }

                }

                // jump timeout
                if (_jumpTimeoutDelta >= 0.0f)
                {

                    _jumpTimeoutDelta -= Time.deltaTime;

                }

            }

            else
            {

                // reset the jump timeout timer
                _jumpTimeoutDelta = JumpTimeout;

                // fall timeout
                if (_fallTimeoutDelta >= 0.0f)
                {

                    _fallTimeoutDelta -= Time.deltaTime;

                }

                else
                {

                    // update animator if using character
                    if (_hasAnimator)
                    {

                        _animator.SetBool(_animIDFreeFall, true);

                    }

                }

                // if we are not grounded, do not jump
                _input.jump = false;

            }

            // apply gravity over time if under terminal (multiply by delta time twice to linearly speed up over time)
            if (_verticalVelocity < _terminalVelocity)
            {

                _verticalVelocity += Gravity * Time.deltaTime;

            }

        }

        private static float ClampAngle(float lfAngle, float lfMin, float lfMax)
        {

            if (lfAngle < -360f) lfAngle += 360f;
            if (lfAngle > 360f) lfAngle -= 360f;
            return Mathf.Clamp(lfAngle, lfMin, lfMax);

        }

        private void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
        {

            Color transparentGreen = new Color(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.35f);
            Color transparentRed = new Color(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.35f);

            if (Grounded) Gizmos.color = transparentGreen;
            else Gizmos.color = transparentRed;

            // when selected, draw a gizmo in the position of, and matching radius of, the grounded collider
            Gizmos.DrawSphere(new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y - GroundedOffset, transform.position.z), GroundedRadius);

        }

        private void OnFootstep(AnimationEvent animationEvent)
        {

            if (animationEvent.animatorClipInfo.weight > 0.5f)
            {

                if (FootstepAudioClips.Length > 0)
                {

                    var index = Random.Range(0, FootstepAudioClips.Length);
                    AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(FootstepAudioClips[index], transform.TransformPoint(_controller.center), FootstepAudioVolume);

                }

            }

        }

        private void OnLand(AnimationEvent animationEvent)
        {

            if (animationEvent.animatorClipInfo.weight > 0.5f)
            {

                AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(LandingAudioClip, transform.TransformPoint(_controller.center), FootstepAudioVolume);

            }

        }

    }

}

I've tried using a SphereCast to detect when the player is attempting to scale a vertical wall, but I haven't had success in getting it to work as expected. I am quite new to Unity and may be approaching this problem incorrectly. So, I decided to start fresh and return to the default character controller setup.

This question is similar to: Character Controller collision and slopes in Unity 3D. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The current code works by allowing the player to jump if Grounded is set to true. Grounded is then updated every frame in the GroundedCheck function by checking to see if there is any object in GroundLayers within a small radius around transform.position.y - GroundedOffset. By tweaking GroundedOffset, you should be able to control how steep a slope the character can climb. The more negative GroundedOffset is, the higher max steepness the player can climb. The less negative GroundedOffset is, the lower the max steepness the player can climb.
